# How many GPUs have support for a particular feature?

Tags: gpu, vulkan

At this [site](http://vulkan.gpuinfo.org/listfeaturescore12.php) under Core 1.2 you can see that descriptorIndexing has 93.67% support across all platforms. Then under extensions [page](http://vulkan.gpuinfo.org/listfeaturesextensions.php) you can see that under VK_EXT_descriptor_indexing all the features are sitting at about 55%, unlike the 93% in the core 1.2 figures. My question is what does this mean? If something is made core in Vulkan 1.2 and a GPU supports Vulkan 1.2, it still may not support descriptorIndexing (which was made core in 1.2)? What do those numbers mean?

Answer (score 2):

Author of that database site here: You are comparing extensions that are (optionally) available before VK 1.2 with dedicated features that became core in 1.2. The dedicated 1.2 feature coverage obviously only counts devices that support at least Vulkan 1.2, while the extension listing by default shows coverage across all devices, down to Vulkan 1.0. If you want comparable numbers, please use the global version selector in the top of the database and select VK 1.2. If you do so, you see that the extension feature numbers match the core feature numbers.

P.S. : If you have questions about may database, please use this [github discussions page](https://github.com/SaschaWillems/vulkan.gpuinfo.org/discussions)

Comment: If a GPU supports for example Vulkan 1.2, and a feature is made core in Vulkan 1.2, that doesn't necessarily mean that the GPU supports that feature, right? Then in what way can it be said that the GPU supports Vulkan 1.2 when it doesn't support a Vulkan 1.2 core feature?

Comment: "If you do so, you see that the extension feature numbers match the core feature numbers." Setting the version selector to 1.2 and above, the core 1.2 feature for bufferdeviceaddress is 95% and under the extensions listing it's 60%. Wow this is really tricky.

Comment: Edit: Wait, the VK_EXT_buffer_device_address is 90%, the VK_KHR_buffer_device_address is 91%, and the core one is 95%, that's with the version selector at the top right set to 1.2 and above.

Comment: That sounds about right. It's a **community driven** database after all, and there will be reports that don't 100% comply to the spec.